# What should I use in a calendar: horizontal scroll or pagination?

Tags: scrolling, data, pagination, calendar

I am working on a calendar in the system to be used on a tablet, and have a question:

[image: Calendar with horizontal scrolling]

[image: Calendar with Show Next 5 Professionals button]

Imagine that you are a store manager and you want to view the calendar (in this case **by week**) for 2 or more professionals who are working at your store. You might want to see, for example, the calendar for 5 professionals at once in a week. So, my question is: which option is better from a UX perspective to let you see more appointments?

P.S. In this system, we are using pagination for tables, and that is why I think that pagination could be a good option for providing consistency. But there might be stronger arguments for horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

If the question is: *which option is better from a UX perspective?*, the best is to let the user decide which kind of interactivity fits better to his/her way of working offering both options.

[image]

Actually, this type of interactivity doesn't need the inclusion of extra buttons or clarification to the user. In the carousels the forward or backward buttons `<` `>` coexist with the horizontal scrolling. The buttons are very useful for desktop and scrolling for smaller screens.

See the carousels at [mattel.com](https://www.mattel.com/en-us)

Comment: I have no objection to horizontal scrolling _per se_; however, I _strongly_ dislike the use of horizontal scroll bars, especially with recent UIs, as there seems to be a tendency to make scroll bars when not in use become invisible or shrink to small sizes which are difficult to trigger.